# Bash read txt and apply conditions to variables

Tags: php, bash

May ask which is correct way to read a file, store the variables into array, and be able to compare them?
PHP user interface writes an txt with 3 variables: weeks's day, hour and minute, i need to read them into bash and compare with the current time to determinate if is to do something or not.
Currently i'm not sure about how i read and store the variables inside a bash array, and i get a lot of issues about how to calculate the condition to determinate if the current time is major then the txt time.
In my case a bash script is running while ever, sometime it finish to do something and need to check if the current time is major then the txt's time to choose what to do next.

The input txt file, an example of the schedule date

```
2
20
45
```

The bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
#CHECKTIME


#GET TIME

IFS=- read -r DAY HOUR MINUTE < <(date +%e-%H-%M)
echo $DAY
echo $HOUR
echo $MINUTE


#READ EVENT TIME
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
done < myFile.txt
echo $line[0]
echo $line[1]
echo $line[2]


if [ "$DAY" =  "$line[0]" ] && [ "$HOUR" -ge  "$line[1]"]  && [ "$MINUTE" > "$line[2]"]
then
    echo "do event "

else
        echo "don't do event"
#echo $name
fi
```

Do i need:
if week's day is equal and hours is major do it, else don't do it, but if week's day and hour are equal check also for minutes equal or major..
?

However im not sure about how i read and store variables into array and how to write this condition in BASH, may ask help for?
Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't do this directly in PHP?

Comment: By bash i drive mp4box, ffmpeg.. i need to check when the live straeming end if there is a new live and is the time to stream it or not

Comment: Question refer to 'weeks day', but sample code code is using 'day of the month` (%e in date). Which one you want to use ?

Comment: From the question, the 'do event' can get triggered multiple times (on the selected day), once the initial time is met. Is this the intention ?

Comment: @MassimoVantaggio : `>`is a redirection operatior in bash. Also, due to the missing space in front of `]`,  you would get an error message `bash: [: missing ']'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement seems to execute a job if the saved date/time matches the current time.

```
   # Ready current Month-day, hour, minute
read CDD CHH CMM <<< (date '+%e %H %M')
   # Read saved time from file
{ read XDD ; read XHH ; read XMM ;} < myFile.txt
   # Check for matching day, and execute if current time >= saved time.
if (( CDD==XDD && CHH*60+CMM >= XHH*60+XMM )) ; then
   echo "Do Event"
else
   echo "Skip"
fi
```